# how to use .catch() in http.request angular2

Tags: angular

I am trying to use http.request in Angular - service::

```
let _request = new Request({
    method: "POST",
    body:body,
    // change url to "./data/data.junk" to generate an error
    url: "http://localhost:5000/user/contact",
    headers:new Headers({
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      'Authorization': 'Bearer '+token
    })
});

return this._http.request(_request)
.map((res:Response) => res.json())
.catch((error:any) => Observable.throw({status:error.status,message:error.json().error}));
```

And in component :

```
this._httpService.getContacts()
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {          
      console.log(response)
    }
  )
```

If response is OK from server. There is no issue. But if I am sending **res.status(401).send({error:err.message})** , I not getting any response in .catch().

Please help

Comment: try: `this._httpService.getContacts().subscribe(
    (response) =>  {console.log(response);} , (error) =>  {console.log(error);} )`

Comment: Now I  am getting the err.message. But how can I get res.status?

Comment: you should be getting it in `error.status` in `.catch()`

Comment: great, i've also posted it as answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to access error do it like :

```
this._httpService.getContacts().subscribe( 
(response) => {console.log(response);} , 
(error) => {console.log(error);} 
)
```

and for status, you can get it as `error.status` in `.catch()`

Answer (score 0):

In HttpClient implementation of Angular 4, you can defined a subscribe method with error callback function like

.subscribe((resp)=>{//resp processing}, (err)=>{//error side})

to be specific try this code below,

```
this._httpService.getContacts()
  .subscribe(
    (response) => {          
      console.log(response)
    },
(err)=>{console.log(err, "Your Error Received from the server")}
  )
```